# Don't Indent After Two Newlines

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've got RET bound to newline-and-indent.  Whenever I skip a line, it leaves a line with no indent and indents the current line, which is how it should be.  In certain circumstances, I'd like it to not indent the current line after skipping.  Some examples:

```
Default behavior
    This is a test.

    Line two.

How I'd like it:
    This is a test.

Line two.
```

I'm not quite sure the best way to go about implementing this.  One solution which just  reeks of inelegance is to try to detect two presses of  in a row and then outdent the current line.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution assumes you want the changes in `text-mode`, adjust the code appropriately if it's a different mode.

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 
          (lambda () (setq indent-line-function 'indent-relative-only-when-previous-has-non-whitespace)))

(defun indent-relative-only-when-previous-has-non-whitespace ()
  "Only call indent-relative when previous line has non whitespace"
  (interactive)
  (when (save-excursion
          (beginning-of-line 0)
          (looking-at "^\\s *\\S "))
    (indent-relative)))
```